# In-page contact form with pop-up form validation and verification

Tags: php, jquery, email, popup

I am looking for a script to send an email. My form is coded in the page with no room for messages. I would like a script that validates the form with a popup and tells the user the email has been sent with the same pop up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I figured out was to use ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest javascript.